# Protecting a jnlp download url?

Tags: java, security, glassfish-3, java-web-start, acc

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 and java web start to deploy a swing ACC application .
The jnlp file is downloaded from this url : localhost:8080/test_application

How can I protect the jnlp url with a password to securise the download ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you create jnlp file dynamically... i.e. create a form and when user click on submit with correct information then create jnlp file and prompt for download.